# Background color changing R

Tags: r, colors, background, header

how could I change color background in dataset just in header (names of columns) in R?
My dataset's name is "logous.df".
I found something like this, but it does not work.

```
 logous.df(data.frame) %>% 
   row_spec(0, background = "yellow")
```

I need to see the color in dataframe saved as table RDS.
Another thing. I created it as matrix and then switch to dataframe (I must do it) and my leading zeroes are gone! How could I give them back? When I tried same operations in dataframe it gives me an error:

```
#any of them did not work
formatC(logous.df, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0")
sprintf("%04.0f", logous.df) 
str_pad(logous.df, 4, pad = "0")
stringr::str_pad(logous.df, 4, side = "left", pad = 0)
```

and error:
Warning message:
In stri_pad_left(string, width, pad = pad) :
argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

Error in sprintf("%04.0f", logous.df) :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Error in storage.mode(x) <- "integer" :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

In addition: Warning message:
In formatC(logous.df, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0") :
class of 'x' was discarded

Answer (score 0):

`row_spec` requires a `knitr::kable` object, so first you should create this object from your dataset before using this function :

```
logous.df %>% data.frame() %>%  knitr::kable() %>% row_spec(0,background="yellow")
```

Comment: And could I do something easier or this is the only possibility? I mean other function or something.

Comment: This is returning: Error in logous.df %>% data.frame() %>% knitr::kable() %>% row_spec(0,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You need to load the dplyr and kableExtra library before running this code : `library(dplyr)` `library(kableExtra)`

Comment: I don't know why, but when I view dataset table, there is still white background, yellow I see just in viewer.